# Keep ImageView on the right size of the text and yet prevent long text to push it out of view?

Tags: android, android-layout

The situation is the same no matter if I use `LinearLayout` or `RelativeLayout`. I think this is a old Android XMl bug, but I have no idea why it still exists.

Namely, in a layout where an `ImageView` is on the right side of a `TextView` can disappear from the screen when text becomes too long. It simply pushes it off the screen. I must NOT make `TextView` single line.

Here is the XML.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="some long text blahblahblahblahblah"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textSize="17sp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    />

<ImageView
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txt"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/key"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I cannot use `layout_weight` attribute as image will then stick to the right side of the screen. It HAS to be on the right side of the text.

Anyone has any ideas how to solve this bug?

Check images when the text is short and long. On the 2nd image the text is long and the image is being pushed away from the screen.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can achieve your task, if you use the `layout_weight` properly. Please refer the code below:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. As you can see it easily handles the long length of the text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"

        />

    <ImageView

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

The output for long text:[image: Output for long text]

The output for short text: [image]

**EDIT:**
This works because of the layout whose width is set as `wrap_content`. If it were `match_parent` then in all cases, all the extra space would have been given to `TextView` because of it's `layout_weight` but since the parent is `wrap_content`, there is no extra space for the `TextView` to fill when the text is small. But when the text is large, the weight property is applied to the `TextView` but since there is no `layout_weight` for the `ImageView` hence, it takes only the amount of space it has to.

Comment: This does not work when LinearLayout's width is match_parent.
Anyway, good answer!

Comment: @geNia making the LinearLayout's width `match_parent` is not the requirement, even if it were, we could easily just nest the LinearLayout in another LinearLayout or some other ViewGroup and make it's width `match_parent`

Comment: Hm, does not seem to work if it's `ListView` row? ListView is set to ˙match_parent` but it's adapter's XML to `wrap_content` - yet it does not work. It behaves the same - image moved to the right side and disappears when text is long.

Comment: @sandalone As i mentioned in the above comment, wrap this whole layout in another LinearLayout and make that `match_parent`. Then it will work.

Comment: Incredible, it works!!! I just had to wrap it inside another layout with `match_parent`. Now, how the heck this work? :) Would you mind editing question to explain why this works.

Answer (score 0):

Set

```
android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
```

for the TextView

and

```
android:layout_marginLeft="-20dp"
```

for the ImageView

You can change the values depending on your needs.

But, if the image can have different sizes, you will have to set margins programmatically.

Comment: Yeah, my fault. Couldn't make it better, because forgot to change LinearLayout's height to wrap_content

Answer (score 0):

there is 2 solutions for these

either set the image as a drawableRight to the textview

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. As you can see it easily handles the long length of the text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textSize="17sp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
```

android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        />

or

alignt the image to right and make textview toleft of the image